# How to return Map<String, Object> in Java, JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have two objects, `Student` and `Book`. `Student` has `@OneToMany` relationship with `Book`, and `Book` has only `id`, `name`, and `publishYear`. What i want is to return from Query is this:

```sql
select s.name, 
       b.name, 
       b.publishYear 
from Student s 
     inner join Book b on s.id = b.studentId
```

How to return `s.name`, `b.name` and `b.publishYear` with map, so i don't want to return a List but a map. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a method `findAll()` which returns a list of with `StudentBook` objects that have properties student name, book name and book publish year.

Now to convert this method to return a map that has as key  the book name and as values are book name and book published year to follow the code below:

```
        Map<String, Book> map = studentBookList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        StudentBook::getSname(), 
                        new Book(StudentBook::getBname(),
                                StudentBook::getPublishYear()
                                )
                        )
                );
```